# Converting an XOR like condition to GP form

Tags: geometric-programming

In my geometric programming optimization problem, I have two decision variables, namely $\epsilon \le X\le 1$ and $\epsilon  \le Y \le 1$. I need an XOR-like condition to impose that if one of them has $\epsilon$ value, the other one should also be $\epsilon$. Further, if one has a value greater than $\epsilon$, the other one should have a value greater than $\epsilon$. How can I show this constraint as the standard geometric programming constraint?

Comment: In GP all variables are strictly positive or you have some nasty unattainmnent issues.

Comment: Yes, I know, I have considered a default epsilon value for all of the variables.